# Python Functions Confusion

Tags: python

I am learning Python. I have a function **readwrite(filename, list)**. filename is of type string. list is a list containing strings to be wtitten in the file.

I have a simple function call like this:

```
fname = 'hello.txt'
readwrite('xx'+fname, datalist)
```

I am facing problem that when i print the filename argument value inside the function definition, i get hello.txt rather than xxHello.txt - a strange thing which i didnt expect
when i do same from commadline, for a sample function, it works fine.
I wonder what I am missing over there.

Here s the code:

```
def readwrite(fileName, list):
    print 'arg file=',filename
    curdir = os.getcwd();
    fullpath = os.path.join(curdir, filename);
    print('full path calculated as: '+fullpath);
    fileExist = os.path.exists(fullpath);
    if(fileExist):
        print 'file exists and opening in \'arw\'mode'
        fiel = open(fileName, 'arw')    # valid only if exists
    else:
        print "file doesnt exist; opening in \'w\'mode"
        fiel = open(fileName, 'w')      # if it doesnt exist, we cant open it for reading as nothing to read.

    for line in list:
        fiel.write('\n'+line)

    print 'position of new pointer = ', fiel.tell()
```

-- main code calling the function:

```
filename = 'put.txt'
strList = ['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you']
readwrite(('xx'+filename), strList);
```

-- second line in fn def ***print 'arg file=',filename*** prints **hello.txt** rather than **xxHello.txt** 
This is my confusion as why is it behaving starngely or am i doing smthing wrong.

Comment: Do not use `list` as a variable name. By doing so you are overwriting the reference to the built in class `list`.

Comment: @aix has already answered about case sensitiveness, I would like just to add that "list" is a built in function and it is not usually a good idea to use it as a name for arguments or variables.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Python is case-sensitive**. The two lines below are referring to two different variables (note the capital "N" in the first one):

```
def readwrite(fileName, list):
    print 'arg file=',filename
```

What's happening is that the second line picks up the global variable called `filename` instead of the function argument called `fileName`.

Comment: +1 thanks a lot. cant do +1 as i dont have 15 reputation
feeling stupid on my mistake.

Comment: @abhinav: But you can accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark to the left of it. Instant +2 rep for you, too. Also, it's not a stupid mistake, and you wrote a very good question. Too bad I can't upvote it more than once. Not many newcomers here know how to write a good question. So don't worry, you'll have enough reputation soon.

Comment: Welcome to the community! Also, btw, all those semicolons at the ends of lines are unnecessary in Python, and it's standard to leave them out. They're ugly :) `fiel` also seems awkward; typical names are `f` and `a_file`.

Comment: also, you don't have to escape the quotes in the string. You can enclose the whole string in double quotes, e.g. `print "file exists and opening in 'arw' mode"`